# HP Intelligent provisioning (An error occurred while installing the system) Land is not defined

Tags: operating-system

i'm trying to install OS through a network interface. also i'm launching console and mounting the shape.  Then i'm doing all steps, but finally  i see the message "ReferenceError:Land is not defined busy.htm:343"

Installation was tested on different images of systems.

Maybe somebody faced with the problem and can help?
[image]

Comment: Wrong site. This one is for programming related questions. Try [su] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Got same error.  HP support says install directly from the ISO not using Intelligent Provisioning.  The error may go away with multiple re-tries, or by updating the Intelligent Provisioning version.